# Cocos2d-html5 light processing

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-html5

I am using cocos2d-html5(http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) engine for my html5 game. I want to add light processing. Something like this http://code.google.com/p/box2dlights/.

Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand dislike of my question.

I found Illuminated.js framework http://greweb.me/2012/05/illuminated-js-2d-lights-and-shadows-rendering-engine-for-html5-applications/. It correspond with my needs of light processing.